# how to get UISessionID inside a stateful EJB?

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly

hiI am developing an EJB application.
I am using wildfly 22, and I want to get the session id of my stateful ejb inside my ejb.
I try to inject @Resource SessionContext and i dont find the session id.

```
@Stateful
@Remote(Connexion.class)
public class ConnexionBean implements Connexion {

    @Resource
    SessionContext sc;
}
```